# Paypal Express checkout completes without adding shipping

Tags: drupal-commerce

Using the commerce kickstart and paypal express checkout modules, a customer is able to place an order without being charged shipping.

Normal credit card orders have shipping quotes on checkout. Is there a special rules setup or similar necessary to make the Paypal module add a shipping quote?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is in the admin Store Settings > Checkout Settings > Look for "Express Checkout review and confirm" under Confirm Order, click configure.
Check Shipping service under "Checkout pane configuration" and save.

Answer (score 0):

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77167/is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-the-paypal-checkout-button-in-cart-view-in-drupal-7

Edit the configuration of the Paypal EC payment method and add a condition to the rule:

Data Comparison / Commerce Order...state / Equal to 'Checkout'

In this way, when the order is still in Shopping Cart state the payment method is disabled.